# MultiBar chart with nvd3 / d3 only shows labels for every other tick on the x-axis. How can I get them all to show up?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Data:

```
nvd3TestData = [
      {
        values:[
          {x:"M",y:1},
          {x:"T",y:2},
          {x:"W",y:3},
          {x:"R",y:3},
          {x:"F",y:4},
          {x:"S",y:5},
          {x:"U",y:6}
        ],
        key:"Apples"
      },
      {
        values:[
          {x:"M",y:5},
          {x:"T",y:2},
          {x:"W",y:6},
          {x:"R",y:8},
          {x:"F",y:2},
          {x:"S",y:4},
          {x:"U",y:1}
        ],
        key:"Zebras"
      }
    ]
```

Creating the chart (pulled from an angularjs directive):

nv.addGraph ->
    chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
      .stacked(true)
      .showControls(false)

```
chart.xAxis
  .axisLabel(attrs.xAxisLabel)

chart.yAxis
  .axisLabel(attrs.yAxisLabel)
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'))


console.log element


d3.select(element[0].children[0])
  .datum(nvd3TestData)
  .call(chart)

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Expected output would have all 7 labels:
M T W R F S U

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I looked on nvd3.org and couldn't find any real documentation, but checking the source, I found https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/multiBarChart.js which showed a boolean chart parameter of "reduceXTicks" with a comment indicating it would do what you want.  I tried it out with one of the example charts and it worked. Specifically, I used:

```
chart
   .reduceXTicks(true)
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I missed that when I looked over the source.

Comment: I think you meant `.reduceXTicks(false)`

Comment: This works, but for my case, the labels are overlapping each other :-(

Comment: @Casperonian stagger them?

Answer (score 2):

There is no proper documentation, but you can acheive it.
Just add the below line to your chart
**reduceXTicks: false**

Rest will follow.
Thanks